# FriendsOfSymfony (FOS) package missing on deployed GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, composer-php

I'm deploying my php 7.4 app with framework symfony 5 on Google App Engine.

The problem is, friendsofsymfony package is nowhere to be seen in the source folder 'vendor' of the deployed app on the App Engine.

I followed the installation of the package on [Symfony FOSCKEditorBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/installation.html)
(Download the bundle, register the bundle, install the assets, configure twig).
I do have the bundle inside of public, but composer doesn't seem to install the ckeditor-bundle package in the vendor folder. Locally everything works fine, upon composer install/update he downloads the package and app runs fine.

**Composer.json**

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2.2",
    "google/cloud-dialogflow": "^0.13.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.2",
    "league/csv": "^9.0",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.0",
    "sendgrid/sendgrid": "^7.7",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/intl": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/notifier": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/string": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/translation": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/validator": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "5.0.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.0.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "5.0.*"
    }
}
```

}

**app.yaml**

```
# Use the PHP 7.3 runtime (BETA) by replacing "php72" below with "php73"
runtime: php74

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: prod
  APP_SECRET: ###
  DATABASE_URL: ###
  # APP_DEBUG: true

  ## For connecting to Cloud SQL with Doctrine
  ## This is used in part two of the README:
  # DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:DB_PASSWORD@localhost?unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=symfonydb

handlers:
  # Declare the build and bundles directory as static assets to be served by the
  # App Engine CDN.
  - url: /build
    static_dir: public
  - url: /bundles
    static_dir: public

  # Declare any media files in the public directory as static assets as well.
  - url: /css
    static_dir: css
  
  - url: /js
    static_dir: js
  
  - url: /images
    static_dir: images
  
  - url: /node_modules
    static_dir: node_modules
  
  - url: /Theme/META-INF/resources
    static_dir: Theme/META-INF/resources
  
  - url: /bundles/fosckeditor
    static_dir: bundles/fosckeditor
  
  

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
```

**fos_ckeditor.yaml**

```
# Read the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/index.html

twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    configs:        
        main_config:
            toolbar:
                - { name: "styles", items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Blockquote', '-', 'Link', '-', 'RemoveFormat', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Image', 'Table', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', 'Source'] }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked for logs of your deployment process?

Comment: Thank you, I've found the issue, I runned the deployment with 'gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache' and it runned 'composer install' again.